# Convert tabs to spaces in a .NET string

Tags: .net, string

I am building a text parser using regular expressions. I need to convert all tab characters in a string to space characters. I cannot assume how many spaces a tab should encompass otherwise I could replace a tab with, say, 4 space characters. Is there any good solution for this type of problem. I need to do this in code so I cannot use an external tool.

---

Unfortunately, none of these answers address the problem with which I am encountered. I am extracting text from external text files and I cannot assume how they were created or which operating system was used to create them. I believe the length of the tab character can vary so if I encounter a tab when I am reading the text file, I want to know how many space characters I should replace it with.

See [Definition of tab stop | PCMag](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/tab-stop) for an explanation of tab stops. See [Tab stop - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop) for historical explanations.

Comment: Some answers here are not aware of the concept of tab stops (see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tab-Stops.html and http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html) . @ckal , Nick-McCowin and user275640 are correct answers.

Comment: @Jonke  posted a new solution to correctly determine tab stop with up to 4 or 8 spaces.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, you need to assume how many spaces a tab represents. You should set this to a fixed value (like the mentioned four) or make it a user option.

The quickest way to do this is .NET is (I'm using C#):

```
var NewString = "This is a string with a    Tab";
var TabLength = 4;
var TabSpace = new String(' ', TabLength);

NewString = NewString.Replace("\t", TabSpace);
```

You can then change the TabLength variable to anything you want, typically as mentioned previously, four space characters.

Tabs in all operating systems are the same length, one tab! What differs is the way software displays them, typically this is the equivalent width of four space characters, and this also assumes that the display is using a fixed width font such as [Courier New](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_%28typeface%29#Courier_New).

For example, my [IDE of choice](http://www.ultraedit.com/) allows me to change the width of the tab character to a value that suits me.

Comment: Tabs account for UP TO TabSpace characters, not exactly that many characters.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn posted a new solution to correctly determine tab stop with up to 4 or 8 spaces.

Comment: This is NOT a solution as it doesn't take into account tabs that are not already tab stop aligned (see @HappyTown answer). Assuming tab width of 4 "aa\tb" becomes "aa____b" not "aa__b"

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure how tabs will read in from a Unix text file, or whatever your various formats are, but this works for inline text.  Perhaps it will help.

```
var textWithTabs = "some\tvalues\tseperated\twith\ttabs";
var textWithSpaces = string.Empty;

var textValues = textWithTabs.Split('\t');

foreach (var val in textValues)
{
    textWithSpaces += val + new string(' ', 8 - val.Length % 8);
}

Console.WriteLine(textWithTabs);
Console.WriteLine(textWithSpaces);
Console.Read();
```

Comment: The concept looks OK, but the += on the string will be VERY SLOW on large strings.

Answer (score 4):

I think what you mean to say is you'd like to replace tabs with the effective amount of spaces they were expanded to. The first way that comes to mind doesn't involve regular expressions (and I don't know that this problem could be solved with them).

- Step through the string character by character, keeping track of your current position in the string.
- When you find a tab, replace it with N spaces, where `N = tab_length - (current_position % tab_length)`.
- Add N to your current position and continue though the string.

Answer (score 3):

*(If you are looking for how to convert tabs to spaces in an editor, see at the end of my answer.)*

I was recently required to replace tabs with spaces.

The solution replaces tab with **up to** 4 or 8 spaces.

The logic iterates through the input string, one character at a time and keeps track of current position (column #) in output string.

- If it encounters `\t` (tab char) - Finds the next tab stop, calculates how many spaces it needs to get to the next tab stop, and replaces \t with those number of spaces.
- If `\n` (new line) - Appends it to the output string and resets the position pointer to 1 on new line. The new lines on Windows are `\r\n` and on Unix (or flavors) use `\n`, so I suppose this should work for both platforms. I have tested on Windows, but don't have Unix  handy.
- Any other characters - Appends it to the output string and increments the position.

.

```
using System.Text;

namespace CSharpScratchPad
{
    class TabToSpaceConvertor
    {
        static int GetNearestTabStop(int currentPosition, int tabLength)
        {
            // If already at the tab stop, jump to the next tab stop.
            if ((currentPosition % tabLength) == 1)
                currentPosition += tabLength;
            else
            {
                // If in the middle of two tab stops, move forward to the nearest.
                for (int i = 0; i < tabLength; i++, currentPosition++)
                    if ((currentPosition % tabLength) == 1)
                        break;
            }

            return currentPosition;
        }

        public static string Process(string input, int tabLength)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return input;

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            int positionInOutput = 1;
            foreach (var c in input)
            {
                switch (c)
                {
                    case '\t':
                        int spacesToAdd = GetNearestTabStop(positionInOutput, tabLength) - positionInOutput;
                        output.Append(new string(' ', spacesToAdd));
                        positionInOutput += spacesToAdd;
                        break;

                    case '\n':
                        output.Append(c);
                        positionInOutput = 1;
                        break;

                    default:
                        output.Append(c);
                        positionInOutput++;
                        break;
                }
            }
            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The calling code would be like:

```
string input = "I\tlove\tYosemite\tNational\tPark\t\t,\t\t\tGrand Canyon,\n\t\tand\tZion";
string output = CSharpScratchPad.TabToSpaceConvertor.Process(input, 4);
```

The output string would get the value:

```
    I   love    Yosemite    National    Park        ,           Grand Canyon,
            and Zion
```

**How do I convert tabs to spaces in an editor?**

If you stumbled upon this question because you could not find the option to convert tabs to spaces in editors (just like I did and thought of writing your own utility for doing it), here is where the option is located in different editors -

```
Notepad++:              Edit → Blank Operations → TAB to Space
Visual Studio:          Edit → Advanced → Untabify Selected Lines
SQL Management Studio:  Edit → Advanced → Untabify Selected Lines
```

Comment: I cannot add the first line of the code, `using System.Text;`, to the code snippet for some reason. Stackoverflow messes up with formatting..

Comment: The last text before the code sample is a list. Lists use the same indentation as code samples to mark a continuation paragraph in the same list item element. I typically use a single period(.) to "reset" the list, and then the code will show correctly.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks for fixing it and showing how to fix it.

Comment: Finally someone that really gets the tabs to spaces conversion idea right!! \o/

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if my solution is more efficient in execution, but it is more compact in code. This is close to [the solution by user *ckal*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508033/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-a-net-string/508524#508524), but reassembles the split strings using the Join function rather than '+='.

```
public static string ExpandTabs(string input, int tabLength)
{
    string[] parts = input.Split('\t');
    int count = 0;
    int maxpart = parts.Count() - 1;
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        if (count < maxpart)
            parts[count] = part + new string(' ', tabLength - (part.Length % tabLength));
        count++;
    }
    return(string.Join("", parts));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what they are talking about needing. I wrote this back in [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline). I made a few quick VB.NET 2010 updates, but it could use some better fixing up for it. Just be sure and set the desired tab width; it's set to 8 in there. Just send it the string, or even fix them right inside the textbox like so:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = strFixTab(RichTextBox1.Text)

Function strFixTab(ByVal TheStr As String) As String
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim T As Integer
    Dim RetStr As String
    Dim ch As String
    Dim TabWidth as Integer = 8    ' Set the desired tab width

    c = 1
    For i = 1 To TheStr.Length
        ch = Mid(TheStr, i, 1)
        If ch = vbTab Then
            T = (TabWidth + 1) - (c Mod TabWidth)
            If T = TabWidth + 1 Then T = 1
            RetStr &= Space(T)
            c += T - 1
        Else
            RetStr &= ch
        End If
        If ch = vbCr Or ch = vbLf Then
            c = 1
        Else
            c += 1
        End If
    Next
    Return RetStr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few answers on here neglect that a tab means *the number of spaces to the next tab stop*, not "four (or eight) spaces". Quite a few answers also neglect carriage returns and line feeds, and therefore don't handle multiline content. So without further ado:

```
    public static string TabsToSpaces(string inTxt, int tabLen=4 )
    {
        var outTxt = new List<string>();

        var textValues = inTxt.Split('\t');

        foreach (var val in textValues)
        {
            var lines = val.Split("\r");
            var preTxt = lines[lines.Length - 1];
            preTxt = preTxt.Replace("\n", "");
            var numSpaces = tabLen - preTxt.Length % tabLen;
            if (numSpaces == 0)
                numSpaces = tabLen;
            outTxt.Add(val + new string(' ', numSpaces));
        }
        return String.Join("", outTxt);
    }
```

(By the way, this is also CPU efficient in that it doesn't recopy giant strings.)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the replace function:

```
char tabs = '\u0009';
String newLine = withTabs.Replace(tabs.ToString(), "    ");
```

Comment: sounds like he wants the results to still line up on tab stops

Comment: Doesn't work as it doesn't take into account tabs that are not already tab stop aligned (see @HappyTown answer). Assuming tab width of 4 "aa\tb" becomes "aa____b" not "aa__b".

Answer (score -1):

```
Regex.Replace(input, "\t", "    ");
```

Comment: Doesn't work as it doesn't take into account tabs that are not tabwidth aligned (see @HappyTown answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "I cannot assume how many spaces a tab should encompass", but this example will replace tabs with any number of spaces you specify.

```
public static string ReplaceTabs(string value, int numSpaces)
{
   string spaces = new String(' ', numSpaces);
   return value.Replace("\t", spaces);     
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work as it doesn't take into account tabs that are not already tab stop aligned (see @HappyTown answer). Assuming tab width of 4 "aa\tb" becomes "aa____b" not "aa__b".

Answer (score -1):

I think everyone has covered it, but a tab character is just that. One character... The character is represented by `\t`. Each application can choose to display it with one space, two spaces, four spaces, a smiley. Whatever... So... there's no real answer to this.

Answer (score -2):

You want to be able to convert a tab to N spaces?   One quick and dirty option is:

```
output = input.Replace("\t", "".PadRight(N, (char)" "));
```

Obviously N has to be defined somewhere, be it user input or elsewhere in the program.