# Funky Square replaces Tab-Space in Label Control

Tags: c#

I have a few tab spaces with my text inside a TextBox, and when I set the Text property of a Label Control to the Text property of the TextBox, it loses those tab spaces and replaces them with squares.

Can anybody please explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the best solution. But it's the only I came up with and it works:

control.Text = control.Text.Replace("\t", "     ");

Comment: see this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508033/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-a-net-string

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing here:

A tab is a control character. I assume the Label control replaces all characters it doesn't have a font glyph for with the funky square.

The TextBox however will have code to display a tab (e.g. 4 spaces).

Answer (score 1):

The tabulator characters are not replaced, they are simply not handled by the Label control.

The TextBox control handles the tabulator characters and makes a space to the next tabulator stop. The Label control doesn't handle the tabulator characters different from any other character, so it's just displayed as it is.

As the tabulator character is not a visible character, it doesn't have any glyph in the font, so the "character missing" glyph is displayed instead, which is a square.

Comment: That's interesting. Would you know how I'd go about getting thos tabs back?

Comment: @baeltazor: Have you tried programmatically replacing them with spaces when you copy the TextBox text to the label?

Comment: um... a little off-topic here... why do people put @ infront of other usernames?

Comment: @baeltazor so you know who the comment is directed at. Imagine if someone later came and left the comment "Have you tried banging your head against the wall?" There would be no way of knowing if your comment "I have actually! I just tried it about 2mins ago and it worked !!! :D" referred to the comment made by Bill or if you somehow fixed it by banging your head against the wall.

Comment: @baeltazor: Getting the tabs back is not an issue, as they didn't go anywhere. If you read the Text property from the Label they are still there. You can replace the tab characters with some spaces if that is the display that you want, but then they will really be gone and you need to store the original string somewhere else if you need it back.